# Java/Selenium - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, junit

When I execute test I have this "java.lang.NullPointerException".
How can I fix this issue? Already check other topics, but still have some troubles.
Will be very pleasured to solve this problem.

Test(login page click):

```
public class MainPage {
private WebDriver driver;

static WebDriver wait;

public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
}

@FindBy (xpath = "//a[text()='Sign in']" )
private WebElement signInButton;

public LoginPage clickSignIn() {
    signInButton.click();
    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

Main:

```
public class MainPageTest {
private WebDriver driver;
private MainPage mainPage;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://github.com");
    mainPage = new MainPage(driver);

}

@Test
public void signInTest(){
    LoginPage loginPage = mainPage.clickSignIn();
    String heading = loginPage.getHeadingText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Sign in to GitHub", heading);
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

LoginPage class:

```
public class LoginPage {
WebDriver driver;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

private By loginField = By.xpath(".//*[@id='login_field']");
private By passwordField = By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']");
private By signInButton = By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']");
private By heading = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'auth-form-   header')]/h1");
private By error = By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-flash-container']//div[@class='container']");
private By createAccLink = By.xpath("//a[text()='Create an account']");
```

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace

Comment: Just debug out the code see which one is throwing NPE

Comment: Provide Login class code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't intialize your page object Model class and hence NULL Pointer exception is throwing. So,, `signInButton` needs to be moved inside the clickSignIn button as below

```
public LoginPage clickSignIn() {
    WebElement signInButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']"));
    signInButton.click();
    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

else

you need to initialize your MainPage class as below

```
    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception is coming because you have not initialized Pagefatory class.

For script writing you can refer below blog

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/