# Errors when running a JUnit test case via Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Here is my Class **Main Page** an

```
    private WebDriver driver;

    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

@FindBy(xpath = "//form/h3")
 private WebElement heading;
```

And here is my method that i want to test by JUnit

```
public String getErrorText(){
return errorMessage.getText();
    }
```

Here my  JUnit class

```
public class MainPageTest {
private WebDriver driver;
private MainPage mainPage;

@Before
public  void setUp(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Intellij IDEA\\testgroup\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://dtapi.if.ua/login");
    mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
}
@Test
public void changeLanguage(){

    String heading = mainPage.getHeadingText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Authorization",heading);
}
```

**But i'm getting an error**:

Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 6024
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1584285941.329][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying..

**And**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException

at MainPage.getHeadingText(MainPage.java:70)
    at MainPageTest.changeLanguage(MainPageTest.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Can you post the stackTrace? Post your entire class code here aswell as you are not providing enough info.

Comment: @RR_IL Checkout the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initated your PageFactory?

Try the following -

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Ref:
[Java/Selenium - java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185170/java-selenium-java-lang-nullpointerexception)